# Search results on Google showing an older title for an SO post -- should I blame caching?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

I posted a question two days ago. It was getting low views, so I edited it, including the title.

After having solved my problem yesterday, I decided to answer my own question (hopefully saving some time for future similarly troubled individuals), and so I did.

While answering, I was doing a Google search for that topic. When Googling, I found that the top result was my question on SO, however, it had the [previously edited title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35591891/revisions).

[image]

Clicking the result brought me to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591891/how-do-i-use-different-card-layouts-for-varying-content) on SO, but with the new, current, edited title.

Just for fun, I searched for the edited name and Google gave me a result, which led me to my question, but this time, Google had the newer title.

[image]

Both results took me to my question.

Out of curiosity, is there a way for search engines like Google to reference older content, since edited out, from SO posts?

[Or should I just blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blame caching.

There's really nothing more to it.

Comment: Oh. How anti-climactic... Thanks

Comment: Blame caching! `:)`